# What to do when your question is marked as duplicate but you don't see how so?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I recently asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/81149/how-to-check-if-a-language-is-regular-or-not), and it was marked as duplicate by a lot of people (obviously a lot more learned than me). I don't realize how so?

I tried all the methods I could understand, but I still failed. I can't post comments, because I don't have enough of reputation. What am I supposed to do? And why is the community so unsparing (downvotes for a legitimate question!)?

Comment: You asked the question? The question says you edited it. Are you the OP of that question too?

Comment: You would probably get more specific guidance at the [per-site Meta](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Sinister typical case of unregistered user creating new account, it's not always auto merged.

Comment: Your question asks "Is this language regular or not ?", and people flagged your question as a duplicate of, [How to prove that a language is not regular?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular) seems pretty simple to me.  The answer to the duplicate question will answer your question about the language your asking about.  If still after reading the duplicate's answer, believe it is not a duplicate, then edit the question and explain in specific detail the reason it is not a duplicate.

Comment: "And why is the community so unsparing (down votes for a legit doubt !) ?" - A down vote is not a personal unsparing thing directed towards you.  It is to indicate there is a problem with the question, and you should fix it, and if you don't know how to fix then ask for assistance in doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you accidentally created another account, and you are the author of the linked question, which was posted from an unregistered account. Had you been signed into the account you posted the question through, the system would have notified you that your question received a duplicate vote:

> **This question may already have an answer here:**
>
> [Title of question]
>
> **<kbd>That solved my problem!</kbd>** No, my question is different. I will edit to explain how.

To respond to some of your statements:

> I can't post comments because I don't have enough of reputation.

While you do have to wait till you gain a reputation of 50 to comment everywhere, *you can comment on your own post regardless of reputation*. As you have logged in from another account, you can't comment on that question since it's not from the same account.

> And why is the community so unsparing (down votes for a legit doubt !)

From [on topic page](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> *Please look around* to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to ask and answer your own question.

Sometimes users downvote a post because they think the OP has not shown some research effort before posting a question. The original of your marked duplicate is a high voted and popular question too (~67k views). The users might have downvoted because they think you haven't searched properly before posting the question.

> What am I supposed to do?

Since you have asked a question from an unregistered account, you were not able to see the duplicate votes or to comment on your post. Request that both the accounts (unregistered and registered one) be merged. For help in merging accounts, see [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)